# Too Many Symbolic Links Encountered

Tags: symlink

This is my script

```
#!/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/bash

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

FOALL() {
export TFUB="/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin"
export BAKFOL="/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/terminfo/z"

export DA="/data/app"
export DD="/data/data"
export DU="/dev/urandom"
export FU="files/UE4Game/ShadowTrackerExtra/ShadowTrackerExtra/Saved"
export SEAD="/data/media/0/Android/data"

export DATEX=$(date "+%A, %d %B %Y")
export DATEY=$(date "+%l:%M %p")

export TM2="/data/local/tmp/.um/tmp"
mkdir -p $TM1/
} 
FOALL

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

CLEANLOG() {
cat > $TM2 <<EOF

exec 3>&2 
exec 2> /dev/null

rm -rf /data/data/$PKG/files/*
rm -rf /data/data/$PKG/app_appcache/*
rm -rf /data/data/$PKG/app_bugly/*
rm -rf /data/data/$PKG/app_crashrecord/*
rm -rf /data/data/$PKG/app_databases/*
rm -rf /data/data/$PKG/app_dex/*
rm -rf /data/data/$PKG/app_geolocation/*
rm -rf /data/data/$PKG/app_tbs/*
rm -rf /data/data/$PKG/app_textures/*
rm -rf /data/data/$PKG/app_webview/*
rm -rf /data/data/$PKG/app_webview_imsdk_inner_webview/*
rm -rf /data/data/$PKG/cache/*
rm -rf /data/data/$PKG/code_cache/*
rm -rf /data/data/$PKG/databases/*
rm -rf /data/data/$PKG/no_backup/*

if [ -e /data/data/$PKG/shared_prefs/device_id.xml ]
then
mv /data/data/$PKG/shared_prefs/device_id.xml /data/data/$PKG/ &&
rm -rf /data/data/$PKG/shared_prefs/* &&
mkdir -p /data/data/$PKG/shared_prefs/ &&
mv /data/data/$PKG/device_id.xml /data/data/$PKG/shared_prefs/ &&
chmod -Rf 555 /data/data/$PKG/shared_prefs/
else
rm -rf /data/data/$PKG/shared_prefs/* &&
chmod -f 771 /data/data/$PKG/shared_prefs/
fi

rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/afd/*
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/config.igm
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/down.voice
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/GameErrorNoRecords
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/IGH5Cache/*
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/ImageDownload/*
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/Logs/*
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/Paks/ODPaks/ClearFlag
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/Paks/ODPaks/ODPaks.bin
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/Paks/puffer_temp/
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/Pandora/*
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/PufferTmpDir/*
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/rawdata/*
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/RoleInfo/*
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/SaveGames/*.json*
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/SaveGames/Activity/
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/SaveGames/AppActivity/
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/SaveGames/Arena/
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/SaveGames/Character/
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/SaveGames/Chat/
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/SaveGames/Competition*
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/SaveGames/Download/
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/SaveGames/Friend/
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/SaveGames/GEM/
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/SaveGames/League*
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/SaveGames/LeagueStatue.json
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/SaveGames/Loading/
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/SaveGames/LobbyBubble/
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/SaveGames/login*
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/SaveGames/loginInfoFile.json
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/SaveGames/mapskill.json
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/SaveGames/Match/
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/SaveGames/Mentor/
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/SaveGames/Notice/
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/SaveGames/pandora/
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/SaveGames/personalprefs*
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/SaveGames/PersonSpace/
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/SaveGames/Pet/
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/SaveGames/playerprefs.json
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/SaveGames/RoleInfo/
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/SaveGames/RP/
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/SaveGames/Season/
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/SaveGames/Store/
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/SaveGames/Task/
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/SaveGames/UnknowPass/
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/Screenshots/*
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/StatEventReportedFlag
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/UpdateInfo/*
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/upload.voice
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/cache/*
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/files/ca-bundle.pem
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/files/cacheFile.txt
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/files/login-identifier.txt
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/files/tbslog/*
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/files/UE4Game/ShadowTrackerExtra/"Epic Games"/*
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/files/UE4Game/ShadowTrackerExtra/Engine/*
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/files/UE4Game/ShadowTrackerExtra/Paks/*
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/files/UE4Game/ShadowTrackerExtra/ShadowTrackerExtra/Content/*
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/files/vmpcloudconfig.json

mv $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/Config/Android/UserCustom.ini $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/Config/UserCustom.ini
mv $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/Config/Android/UserSettings.ini $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/Config/UserSettings.ini
mv $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/Config/Android/EnjoyCJZC.ini $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/Config/EnjoyCJZC.ini
rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/Config/Android/*
mv $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/Config/UserCustom.ini $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/Config/Android/UserCustom.ini
mv $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/Config/UserSettings.ini $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/Config/Android/UserSettings.ini
mv $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/Config/EnjoyCJZC.ini $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/Config/Android/EnjoyCJZC.ini
chmod -Rf 555 $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/Config/

rm -rf /config/sdcardfs/$PKG
rm -rf /data/media/0/.backups
rm -rf /data/media/0/.cc
rm -rf /data/media/0/.um
rm -rf /data/media/0/.uxx
rm -rf /data/media/0/.a.dat
rm -rf /data/media/0/legacy
rm -rf /data/media/0/MidasOversea
rm -rf /data/media/0/osmini
rm -rf /data/media/0/QTAudioEngine
rm -rf /data/media/0/tbs
rm -rf /data/media/0/tencent
rm -rf /data/media/0/.profig.os
rm -rf /data/system/graphicsstats/*
rm -rf /data/user_de/0/$PKG
rm -rf /data/media/0/Android/obj

killall -q $PKG:networkDetector; killall -q $PKG:networkDetector; killall -q $PKG:networkDetector
killall -q $PKG:xg_service_v4; killall -q $PKG:xg_service_v4; killall -q $PKG:xg_service_v4
killall -q $PKG:ping; killall -q $PKG:ping; killall -q $PKG:ping

#rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/Paks/puffer_res.eifs
#rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/Paks/puffer_res.eifsbk
#rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/Paks/apollo_reslist.flist
#rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/Paks/apollo_reslist.flistnewlist
#rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/Paks/PufferFileList.json
#rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/Paks/filelist.json
#rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/Paks/new.filelist
#rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/Paks/new.filelist.mottd
#rm -rf $SEAD/$PKG/$FU/Paks/*cures*

exec 2>&3
exec 3>&-

EOF
bash $TM2 ; rm -rf $TM2
}

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

SUICIDE() {
cat > $TM2 <<EOF

exec 3>&2 
exec 2> /dev/null

export TFH="/data/data/com.termux/files/home/"

rm -rf *gr*
rm -rf *xz*
rm -rf *gb*
rm -rf *vn*
rm -rf *kr*
rm -rf *tw*
rm -rf *fix*
rm -rf *xyz*
rm -rf *xyy*
rm -rf *IISomeOneII*
rm -rf *KATYUSHA*

rm -rf $TFUB/*gr*
rm -rf $TFUB/*xz*
rm -rf $TFUB/*gb*
rm -rf $TFUB/*vn*
rm -rf $TFUB/*kr*
rm -rf $TFUB/*tw*
rm -rf $TFUB/*fix*
rm -rf $TFUB/*xyz*
rm -rf $TFUB/*xyy*
rm -rf $TFUB/*IISomeOneII*
rm -rf $TFUB/*KATYUSHA*

rm -rf $TFH/*gr*
rm -rf $TFH/*xz*
rm -rf $TFH/*gb*
rm -rf $TFH/*vn*
rm -rf $TFH/*kr*
rm -rf $TFH/*tw*
rm -rf $TFH/*fix*
rm -rf $TFH/*xyz*
rm -rf $TFH/*xyy*
rm -rf $TFH/*IISomeOneII*
rm -rf $TFH/*KATYUSHA*

exec 2>&3
exec 3>&-

EOF
bash $TM2 ; rm -rf $TM2
}

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

clear ; reset -Q
export SH=$(basename "$0")
export SHX=$(echo "${SH,,}")

echo -e "\a\n\t [[ INITIALIZING KATYUSHA ]]"
export CODE="$SHX"
export SHNAME="$SHX"
export VRSNX="065"
export EXP="2020-03-16"

if [ "$SH" = "xz" ]
then
VRSN=$VRSNX
echo -e "\a\t [[  SCRIPT VERSION: $VRSN  ]]"
echo -e "\a\t [[ CONNECT TO  INTERNET! ]]"
sleep $(shuf -i 0-2 -n 1)s
else
echo -e "\n\a SCRIPT NAME [$SH] DOESN'T MATCH \n"
sleep 2.5s
clear ; reset -Q
killall -q com.termux ; pkill com.termux > /dev/null 2>&1
exit
fi

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

if [ "$(whoami)" != "root" ]
then
echo -e "\a\n PLEASE RUN AS ROOT! \n DON'T FORGET TO TYPE \"tsu\" \n"
sleep 2.5s
clear ; reset -Q
killall -q com.termux ; pkill com.termux > /dev/null 2>&1
exit
fi

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

if [ ! -e $TFUB/ssl ]
then
echo -e "\n\a PLEASE RUN \"./fix\" FIRST! \n"
sleep 2.5s
clear ; reset -Q
killall -q com.termux ; pkill com.termux > /dev/null 2>&1
exit
fi

export FIXED=$(head -n 1 $TFUB/ssl)
if [ "$FIXED" != "fixed065" ]
then
echo -e "\n\a PLEASE RUN \"./fix\" FIRST! \n"
sleep 2.5s
clear ; reset -Q
killall -q com.termux ; pkill com.termux > /dev/null 2>&1
exit
fi

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

export SOURC=$(curl -s --head http://pastebin.com)
if [ "$SOURC" = "" ]
then
echo -e "\a\n   CAN'T CONNECT TO THE SERVER... \a\t"
echo -e "\a\n   PLEASE CHECK YOUR INTERNET CONNECTION!\a\n\t"
sleep 2.5s
clear ; reset -Q
killall -q com.termux ; pkill com.termux
fi

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

: & ping -s 1 119.81.42.42 > /dev/null 2>&1 & :

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

export MONTHRAW=$(echo -e "$SOURC" | grep "^Date:" | sed 's/Date: //g' | cut -b 9-11)
if [ "$MONTHRAW" == "Jan" ]
then
export MONTH="01"
elif [ "$MONTHRAW" == "Feb" ]
then
export MONTH="02"
elif [ "$MONTHRAW" == "Mar" ]
then
export MONTH="03"
elif [ "$MONTHRAW" == "Apr" ]
then
export MONTH="04"
elif [ "$MONTHRAW" == "May" ]
then
export MONTH="05"
elif [ "$MONTHRAW" == "Jun" ]
then
export MONTH="06"
elif [ "$MONTHRAW" == "Jul" ]
then
export MONTH="07"
elif [ "$MONTHRAW" == "Aug" ]
then
export MONTH="08"
elif [ "$MONTHRAW" == "Sep" ]
then
export MONTH="09"
elif [ "$MONTHRAW" == "Oct" ]
then
export MONTH="10"
elif [ "$MONTHRAW" == "Nov" ]
then
export MONTH="11"
elif [ "$MONTHRAW" == "Dec" ]
then
export MONTH="12"
fi

export YEAR=$(echo -e "$SOURC" | grep "^Date:" | sed 's/Date: //g' | cut -b 13-16)
export DATE=$(echo -e "$SOURC" | grep "^Date:" | sed 's/Date: //g' | cut -b 6-7)

export CHECK=$(date -d "$YEAR-$MONTH-$DATE" +%s)
export EXPIRED=$(date -d "$EXP" +%s)
if (("$CHECK" <= "$EXPIRED"))
then
:
else
echo -e "\a\n\t SCRIPT EXPIRED! \a\n\t"
exec 3>&2 
exec 2> /dev/null
SUICIDE
sleep 2.5s
clear ; reset -Q
killall -q com.termux ; pkill com.termux
exit
exec 2>&3
exec 3>&-
fi

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

export SBM="/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include/c++/v1/support/android/misc"
if [ ! -e $SBM/zram ]
then
exec 3>&2 
exec 2> /dev/null
mkdir -p $SBM/
head -c $(shuf -i 1024-5120 -n 1) $DU > $SBM/zram
exec 2>&3
exec 3>&-
fi

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

echo -e "\a\n FOR SQUIDWARD VIP MEMBERS ONLY \a\n TELEGRAM CHANNEL: t.me/IIISomeOneIII \a\n"
echo -e "\a CREATORs: \a\n ¬ SquidWard A.K.A. @IISomeOneII \a\n THANK YOU FOR TRUSTING OUR SERVICES \a\n\n DATE: $DATEX \a\n TIME:$DATEY \n"

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

export CHC1=$(curl -s https://pastebin.com/raw/3gH9E1SU | grep -wo "SquidWard-VIP" | tail -1)
if [ "$CHC1" = "SquidWard-VIP" ]
then
export CSC=$(curl -s https://pastebin.com/raw/3gH9E1SU)
export TPC=C
else
export CHC2=$(wget -qO - https://pastebin.com/raw/3gH9E1SU | grep -wo "SquidWard-VIP" | tail -1)
if [ "$CHC2" = "SquidWard-VIP" ]
then
export CSC=$(wget -qO - https://pastebin.com/raw/3gH9E1SU)
export TPC=W
fi
fi

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

export DTD=$(sha1sum $SBM/zram | cut -f 1 -d ' ')
echo -ne "\a  PREPARE TO LOGIN"
sleep 0.$(shuf -i 1-9 -n 1)s
echo -ne "."
sleep 0.$(shuf -i 1-9 -n 1)s
echo -ne "."
sleep 0.$(shuf -i 1-9 -n 1)s
echo -ne "."
sleep 0.$(shuf -i 1-9 -n 1)s
echo -ne "."
sleep 0.$(shuf -i 1-9 -n 1)s
echo -e "."

export CFR1=$(echo -e "$CSC" | grep "GTX.*$DTD" | grep -wo "$DTD" | head -n 1)
export CFR2=$(echo -e "$CSC" | grep "GTX.*$DTD" | grep -wo "VIP" | head -n 1)

DEL=$(echo -e "$CSC" | grep "GTZ.*$DTD" | grep -wo "GTZ" | head -n 1)
if [ "$DEL" = "GTZ" ]
then
echo -e "\a\n  ACCOUNT EXPIRED! \a\n\t"
exec 3>&2 
exec 2> /dev/null
SUICIDE
sleep 2.5s
clear ; reset -Q
killall -q com.termux ; pkill com.termux
exit
exec 2>&3
exec 3>&-
fi

if [ "$DTD" = "$CFR1" ]
then
echo -e "\a  SN: $DTD VALID!"
else
echo -e "\a  SN: $DTD INVALID! \n\a  SN GENERATED TO INTERNAL STORAGE! \n"
echo -e "$DTD" > /data/media/0/"Serial Number.txt"
exec 3>&2 
exec 2> /dev/null
SUICIDE
sleep 2.5s
clear ; reset -Q
killall -q com.termux ; pkill com.termux
exit
exec 2>&3
exec 3>&-
fi

if [ "$CFR2" = "VIP" ]
then
echo -e "\a  VIP MEMBERSHIP: ON"
export VIPX=ON
else
echo -e "\a  VIP MEMBERSHIP: OFF"
export VIPX=OFF
fi

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

export CODE="NULL"
if [ "$1" = "gb" ] || [ "$1" = "com.tencent.ig" ] || [ "$1" = "global" ]
then
export CODE="gb"
elif [ "$1" = "vn" ] || [ "$1" = "com.vng.pubgmobile" ] || [ "$1" = "vietnam" ]
then
export CODE="vn"
elif [ "$1" = "kr" ] || [ "$1" = "com.pubg.krmobile" ] || [ "$1" = "korea" ]
then
export CODE="kr"
elif [ "$1" = "tw" ] || [ "$1" = "com.rekoo.pubgm" ] || [ "$1" = "taiwan" ]
then
export CODE="tw"
else
export CODE="NULL"
echo -e "\a\n   INPUT VALID VERSION! \n"
sleep 2.5s
clear ; reset -Q
killall -q com.termux ; pkill com.termux
exit
fi

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

export PKG="NULL"

case "$CODE" in
"gb"|"com.tencent.ig"|"global")
 echo -e "\a\n   PACKAGE NAME: com.tencent.ig \a\n   VERSION: GLOBAL"
 export PKG="com.tencent.ig"
 export PKN="GLOBAL"
 if [ -d /data/data/com.tencent.ig ]; then
 :
 else
 echo -e "\a\n   GLOBAL VERSION IS NOT INSTALLED! \n"
 sleep 2.5s
 clear ; reset -Q
 killall -q com.termux ; pkill com.termux
 exit
 fi;;
"vn"|"com.vng.pubgmobile"|"vietnam")
 echo -e "\a\n   PACKAGE NAME: com.vng.pubgmobile \a\n   VERSION: VIETNAM"
 export PKG="com.vng.pubgmobile"
 export PKN="VIETNAM"
 if [ -d /data/data/com.vng.pubgmobile ]; then
 :
 else
 echo -e "\a\n   VIETNAM VERSION IS NOT INSTALLED! \n"
 sleep 2.5s
 clear ; reset -Q
 killall -q com.termux ; pkill com.termux
 exit
 fi;;
"kr"|"com.pubg.krmobile"|"korea")
 echo -e "\a\n   PACKAGE NAME: com.pubg.krmobile \a\n   VERSION: KOREA"
 export PKG="com.pubg.krmobile" 
 export PKN="KOREA"
 if [ -d /data/data/com.pubg.krmobile ]; then
 :
 else
 echo -e "\a\n   KOREAN VERSION IS NOT INSTALLED! \n"
 sleep 2.5s
 clear ; reset -Q
 killall -q com.termux ; pkill com.termux
 exit
 fi;;
"tw"|"com.rekoo.pubgm"|"taiwan")
 echo -e "\a\n   PACKAGE NAME: com.rekoo.pubgm \a\n   VERSION: TAIWAN"
 export PKG=com.rekoo.pubgm
 export PKN="TAIWAN"
 if [ -d /data/data/com.rekoo.pubgm ]; then
 :
 else
 echo -e "\a\n   TAIWAN VERSION IS NOT INSTALLED! \n"
 sleep 2.5s
 clear ; reset -Q
 killall -q com.termux ; pkill com.termux
 exit
 fi;;
*)
 echo -e "\a\n   INVALID SCRIPT NAME! \n"
 sleep 2.5s
 clear ; reset -Q
 killall -q com.termux ; pkill com.termux
 exit
esac

if [ "$PKG" = "NULL" ]
then
export PKN=NULL
sleep 2.5s
clear ; reset -Q
killall -q com.termux ; pkill com.termux
exit
fi

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

cat > $TM2 <<EOF

exec 3>&2 
exec 2> /dev/null
mount -o rw,remount /system
mount -o rw,remount /
mount -o rw /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system /system
mount -o rw,remount -t ext4 /system
mount -o rw,remount /system
/system/bin/ip6tables -P INPUT DROP
/system/bin/ip6tables -P FORWARD DROP
/system/bin/ip6tables -P OUTPUT DROP
exec 2>&3
exec 3>&-

EOF
bash $TM2 ; rm -rf $TM2

echo -e "\a\n    DISABLING IPV6..."

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

PREFIX() {
cat > $TM2 <<EOF

exec 3>&2 
exec 2> /dev/null
mkdir -p $BAKFOL/
export HLC="/system/etc/hosts"
cp -f $HLC $BAKFOL/hosts
cat $HLC > $BAKFOL/hosts
cp -f $HLC $BAKFOL/hosts
cat $HLC > $BAKFOL/hosts
cp -f $HLC $BAKFOL/hosts
cat $HLC > $BAKFOL/hosts
echo -e "" > $HLC
echo -e "" >> $HLC
echo "
127.0.0.1 allhosts
127.0.0.1 allnodes
127.0.0.1 allrouters
127.0.0.1 broadcasthost
127.0.0.1 localdomain
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 localnet
127.0.0.1 loopback
127.0.0.1 mcastprefix
::1 ip6-allhosts
::1 ip6-allnodes
::1 ip6-allrouters
::1 ip6-localdomain
::1 ip6-localhost
::1 ip6-localnet
::1 ip6-loopback
::1 ip6-mcastprefix
" > $HLC
exec 2>&3
exec 3>&-

EOF
bash $TM2 ; rm -rf $TM2
} 
PREFIX

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

cat > $TM2 <<EOF

exec 3>&2 
exec 2> /dev/null
chattr -R -i /data/data/$PKG/ &
chattr -R -i /data/app/*$PKG-*/ &
chattr -R -i $SEAD/$PKG/ &
chattr -R -i /data/media/0/

find $SEAD/$PKG/ -type d -print0 | xargs  -0 chmod 755 
find /data/data/$PKG/ -type d -print0 | xargs  -0 chmod 771 
find $SEAD/$PKG -type f -print0 | xargs  -0 chmod 644
exec 2>&3
exec 3>&-

EOF
bash $TM2 ; rm -rf $TM2

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

GETPM() {
cat > $TM2 <<EOF

exec 3>&2 
exec 2> /dev/null
mkdir -p $BAKFOL/
chmod -f 777 $BAKFOL/
wget --no-check-certificate 'https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1EDcC7d_TOhKJor3VowLH08kwqw9sgifj&export=download' -qO $BAKFOL/qwerty
chmod -f 644 $BAKFOL/qwerty
unzip -qo $BAKFOL/qwerty -d $BAKFOL/
rm -rf $BAKFOL/qwerty
chmod -f 644 $BAKFOL/IISomeOneII
exec 2>&3
exec 3>&-

EOF
bash $TM2 ; rm -rf $TM2
}
GETPM

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
```

The error log is

```
./xz: line 564: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/rm: Too many symbolic links encountered
./xz: line 571: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/cat: Too many symbolic links encountered
./xz: line 608: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/bash: Too many symbolic links encountered
./xz: line 608: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/rm: Too many symbolic links encountered
./xz: line 614: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/cat: Too many symbolic links encountered
./xz: line 630: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/bash: Too many symbolic links encountered
./xz: line 630: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/rm: Too many symbolic links encountered
./xz: line 635: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/cat: Too many symbolic links encountered
./xz: line 650: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/bash: Too many symbolic links encountered
./xz: line 650: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/rm: Too many symbolic links encountered
```

Is there something wrong?

Answer (score 6):

There is a circular chain of symbolic links, probably a symbolic link pointing directly to itself. (Or there's a chain that's too long, but this is extremely unlikely.)

Something is wrong in your BusyBox installation: probably `…/bin/busybox` is a symbolic link to itself instead of being the actual binary. The others should be a symbolic link to `busybox`. Fix your BusyBox installation.

Comment: IIRC, shell detects (and gives up) when it has followed more than 50 soft links when trying to find an actual target file.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant, 50 deep is way over the top. I doubt I've ever seen chains of more than 3 or 4 symlinks in the wild.

Comment: @vonbrand. The limit is meant to be over the top to prevent false aborts. IIRC, RedHat used to warn "more than 50 levels of link found", and this forum says Linux does 40 levels before it quits. But as you say, the most convoluted installation shouldn't get past a handful. Things like Oracle seem to enjoy managing upgrades like that, though.

Comment: I changed my question

Comment: @Paul_Pedant It's not the shell, it's the kernel.

Comment: @IISomeOneII Please do not change your question in a way that invalidates answers. Anyway, the problem is not in your script, it's your installation of BusyBox. If you want to modify your script to cope with this broken installation, post a **new question**, with an **explanation of what you want to do** (not just your code: what do you want to do with it?), and post a **[short, self-contained](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)** script (not hundreds of lines).

Comment: This can be diagnosed on paper very easily. Start with `ls -l /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/cat` and write down the name to the right of -> (or paste it into an editor window). Then ls -l that name, and iterate. Within about 5 shots, you will find a link that points to itself, or to something earlier in the list. Then post that list, unless you can figure what is broke.